# Setting up LaTeX with Sublime Text 2 - Linux

Tags: texlive, linux, debian, sublime-text

I'm looking for some help setting ST2 up with LaTeX, so far I have downloaded texLive from [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) and have uncompressed it and ran `./install-tl`. I have also installed `LaTeXTools` on ST2. When I try to build a LaTeX document I get the following error:

```
COULD NOT COMPILE!

Attempted command:latexmk -cd -e $pdflatex='pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O' -f -pdf /home/colin/workspace/trunk/Documents/My Papers/Template/template.tex
```

I've also add it to my `$PATH` using `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux`.

Comment: According to your `debian` tag, you use debian. So you should install LaTeX by installing the texlive package (and not downloading it from the web).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The official web page of ST2](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) explains how to install ST2 on linux (you seems to use debian).

> Linux support is coming along nicely. You need to install TeXlive; if
>   you are on Ubuntu, note that apt-get install texlive will get you a
>   working but incomplete setup. In particular, it will not bring in
>   latexmk, which is essential to LaTeXTools. You need to install it via
>   apt-get install latexmk. If on the other hand you choose to install
>   the TeXlive distro from TUG, latexmk comes with it, so you don't need
>   to do anything else. Also, to get inverse search working on ST3, make
>   sure you set the sublime option in LaTeXTools
>   Preferences.sublime-settings correctly; the Ubuntu package from the ST
>   web page uses subl, but check from the command line first.

so :

```
apt-get install texlive latexmk
```

Comment: Can I just delete the current texlive directories or is there a "safe" way to remove it?

Comment: it's depends what commands did you passed. But the short answer is yes, it's safe. Remove your folder and install via apt-get.